# Accumulated sum hierachy - power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

I am managing a database where the field "**Valor**" represents product values, and "**CORTE**" indicates the date of the data. Additionally, a hierarchical structure is established among the fields `["Nombre_region," "Nombre_zona," "Nombre_SUC," "Asesor."]`

The **"Saldo del día"** signifies the cumulative sum of values for each day. In Power BI, calculating this is straightforward – placing it in a table or matrix automatically generates the sum.

Regarding the **"Acumulado mensua"** it entails summing the **"Saldo del día"** for days within the current month, up to a specified date provided by a filter with a dropdown list.

However, I have encountered an issue where the **"Acumulado mensual"** yields the same value across the entire hierarchy. When applying a filter, it consistently provides the same value for the lowest category in the hierarchy.

I am seeking guidance on modifying my query to ensure that the **"Acumulado mensual"** reflects the average of the sum for each day's **"Saldo del día"**

My database looks like something like this:

[image]

The formula that I’m using to calculate “Acumulado mensual” is:

```
AcumuladoMensual =

CALCULATE(

    SUMX(

        FILTER(

            ALL(CDT),

            YEAR(CDT[CORTE]) = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[CORTE])) &&

            MONTH(CDT[CORTE]) = MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[CORTE])) &&

            CDT[CORTE] <= SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[CORTE]) &&

            CDT[Asesor] = SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[Asesor]) &&

            CDT[Nombre_region] = SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[Nombre_region]) &&

            CDT[Nombre_zona] = SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[Nombre_zona]) &&

            CDT[Nombre_SUC] = SELECTEDVALUE(CDT[Nombre_SUC])

        ),

        CDT[Valor]

    )

)
```

And the result I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "Acumulado mensual," it entails summing the "Saldo del día" for days within the current month, up to a specified date provided by a filter with a dropdown list.

Do you have a Calendar table?

```
CALCULATE ( [Total Sales],
FILTER( ALL('DimDate'),
            'DimDate'[Year]=MAX('DimDate'[Year]) &&
            'DimDate'[MonthNo]=MAX('DimDate'[MonthNo]) && 
            'DimDate'[DayOfMonth]<=MAX('DimDate'[DayOfMonth])
    ) )
```

Oh, the date in the dropdown... 'DimDate'[Date]<=SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[Date])... just AND that on using &&

Answer (score 0):

Leverage DAX [Time Intelligence functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax):

```
AcumuladoMensual = TOTALMTD( CDT[Valor], CDT[CORTE] )
```